# No response in JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I don't understand why this code is not working:

```
var cat;
  var api = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var finalUrl =
    "https://cleanuri.com/api/v1/shorten";
  api.open("POST", finalUrl);
  api.send('url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F');
  api.onload = (e) =>{
  cat = api.responseText;
  console.log(cat);
  };
```

I wanted to get a shortened URL but this code doesn't seem to be working. I have modified a lot but couldn't run it. Can anyone give me any reasons or idea!
**Thanks in advance :-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call this API in server side. Like Node.js、Shell、Python.

---

If you want test this API in browser,

1. go to https://cleanuri.com/. Other website will fail because of CORS policy.
2. open development mode and change to Console panel
3. execute

```js
  var cat;
  var api = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var finalUrl = "https://cleanuri.com/api/v1/shorten";
  api.open("POST", finalUrl, true);
  api.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); # this line is new added
  api.send('url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F');
  api.onload = (e) =>{
    cat = api.responseText;
    console.log(cat);
  };
```

4. the result
   `{"result_url":"https:\/\/cleanuri.com\/AqJYaW"}`